# What exactly happens when you put the use statement before the namespace statement in PHP?>

Tags: php, namespaces

```
<?php
namespace A;
Use \B\C;
C::bar();
```

This will throw this error: Class 'B\C' not found

(use working)

```
<?php
Use \B\C;
namespace A;
C::bar();
```

This will throw this error: Class 'A\C' not found

(use not working)

The [manpage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) says:

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the
> global scope) or inside namespace declarations.

If the use keyword has to come before the namespace, shouldn't it throw a compile error or a warning otherwise?
Or what exactly happens if the use keyword is used before the namespace keyword? Does namepsace keyword reset the imports done with the use keyword?

Comment: FYI, you don’t need the initial backslash in a `use` statement, as it’s always fully qualified.

Comment: In the first example you've changed the current namespace to `A` and imported `B\C` into it. In the second example you've imported `B\C` into the Global namespace, and then changed the current namespace to `A`. It's totally valid syntax, just... don't do that.

Comment: For the most part, statements in the PHP language are actually *active,* not declarations.  They are *executed,* and when they are executed they *do* something.  PHP is not at all consistent about error/warning messages, and for the most part assumes that you know what you intend to be doing ... even when you made a mistake.  If there's any way for PHP to "keep going," with or without a warning message, it generally will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use` applies to the namespace it was declared in. Thus, your first example means, "*For code in the `A` namespace, `C` means `\B\C`,*" and your code is in the `A` namespace, so the alias triggers. Your second example means, "*For code in no namespace, `C` means `\B\C`,*" but your code is in the the `A` namespace, so the alias does not trigger. It might help to think of your examples like this:

```
namespace A {
    use B\C;
    C::bar();
}
```

And:

```
use B\C;
namespace A {
    C::bar();
}
```